# arXiv link doesn't redirect to arXiv

Tags: bibtex, arxiv

I used makebst to create a bib style. Everything works fine, except for the arXiv number of articles: it's blue, like the links are supposed to be, but clicking on it does nothing. Is it something that I did wrong while using makebst or do I need to add something to my bib style file?
Thanks

I did load hyperref, which works for formulas and similar things.

my bibtex entries are

```
@article{Maldacena2013,
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
arxivId = {1306.0533},
author = {Maldacena, Juan and Susskind, Leonard},
eprint = {1306.0533},
month = jun,
pages = {48},
title = {{Cool horizons for entangled black holes}},
year = {2013}
}
```

Using a different bst file, I can directly click on the arXiv number and I'm sent to the arXiv pages. But I guess I need to add something to the one I'm using now so that the same happens here. I'm not sure whether makebst already includes a similar mechanism to the style file it produces, or I need to add something by hand.

The bib style file is here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/70990785/bibstyle.bst
I see two possible solutions: either I substitute every eprint field in my bibliography by
\href{http: //arxiv.org/abs/1306.0533}{1306.0533}. This gives a problem however, "\eprint doesn't match its definition".
Otherwise I should tell him to send me to http://arxiv.org/abs/... and then the number of the eprint, but I don't know how to do it

Comment: Hi and welcome, a few questions: Did you load `hyperref`? Doe the links work with a file we all can use? Can you try to boil down an exampke and post it on site?

Comment: Without seeing any code, how should we know?

Comment: And can we see your bibtex data, i.e. what you write that then becomes a link.

Comment: I added my bib entries, if I need to add part of my .bst file which one should that be, since the file is really long?

Comment: You can make it available completely (how else shall we test) by uploading it to dropbox or something like that.

Comment: btw: Would `biblatex` be an option for you? You can modify the appearance of cites and the bibliography using LaTeX commands. You need a hour or two to get into the matter, but then you are much more flexible.

Comment: I put a link to the bib file

Comment: A quick comment: Since the entry in question isn't a "normal" journal article, you probably shouldn't use the `@article` entry type for it; have you tried `@misc` instead?

Comment: Most of the articles that are used in my field are only on arXiv. I haven't tried using `@misc` but I don't see how that could solve the link problem